# Unable to delete mysql data from php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have successfully connected to database and published mysql data on web and manually added joke on it.Screenshot of what output looks like is provided here.
[image]

When i manually enter the corresponding id of joke inside the textbox and press delete button, it deletes the joke corresponding to that it. But when i click on the delete button directly, that joke isn't deleted. How to update value of that textbox ? For the time being, i have made input type of textbox as text so to see whats going inside it. I am using PHP version: 7.1.1 and Apache/2.4.25 (Win32.

```
<p><a href="?addjoke">Add your own joke</a></p>
<p>Here are all the jokes in the database:</p>
<?php foreach ($jokes as $joke) : ?>
  <form action ="?deletejoke" method='post'>
  <blockquote>
    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($joke['text'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');?>
    <input type = "text" name = "id" value = "<? php echo $joke['id']; ?>">
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Delete'>
    </p>
  </blockquote>
</form>
```

Screenshot of Mysql database is provided here.
[image]

Comment: where is the php code?

Comment: delete the space between `?` and `php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a space between `<?` and `php` on the input value it should be `<?php`;
then it should work.

```
<input type = "text" name = "id" value = "<? php echo $joke['id']; ?>">
```

Comment: @AbhayaSinghPandey accept the answer, that informs the community that solution was found

Comment: five minutes is still remaining before i can accept it as final solution. As soon as time period to perform this action begins, i wll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $joke['id'];?> ">
```

you should remove the spaces (not just in this line)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<input type = "text" name = "id" value = "<? php echo $joke['id']; ?>">
```

to

```
<input type = "text" name = "id" value = "<?php echo $joke['id']; ?>">
```